# Ajax call form different domain with jQuery not rendering proper data

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js

I have this code in javascript

```
var url = 'http://mydomain.com:3000';
url += "/user";

jQuery.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  async: false,
  success: function (data) {alert(1);
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

where my site runs on http://mydomain.com:80 so they are not in the same server.

http://mydomain.com:3000 is served by nodejs with the code

```
app.get('/user',function(req,res){    
  var result = {
    result:-1
  };
  res.json(result);
  res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
});
```

When I call the ajax I get from the chrome preview response

```
{
  "result": -1
}
```

but in the console of the javascript I got the error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : user:2
```

and I don't get any alert message.

I even tried in nodejs

```
res.end("'"+JSON.stringify(result)+"'");
```

and the chrome preview response is

```
'{"result":-1}'
```

and the console error is gone but still the alert is not triggered

Comment: `async: false` - **bad idea**. Not that it'll make a difference when using JSONp...

Comment: look into cross-origin resource sharing? http://enable-cors.org/ (enables you to do ajax call without jsonp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`res.json()` sends the response immediately. You have to set headers before using this.

```
res.json(result);
res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"}); //Response already sent before.
```

So `res.writeHead()` does not set header in response. The error that you are getting means that there is some illegal character code in your response.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : user:2

Try setting headers before, browser will then correctly identify your message as JSON.

**Update**

On checking your code again I saw that you are sending response as `res.json()` but in your AJAX recieving it as `jsonp`. The two are different `json` and `jsonp`. There is a `res.jsonp()` you can use in node or change datatype in your AJAX query as `json`.

Comment: I tried before with 
            res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
            res.end(JSON.stringify(result)); but it gives me the same error